# How to read PDF file from right to left on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, ios6

I am working on a basic project that reads pdf files from a server and show them on the screen.
The issue is that i want to read that files from right to left as a page.

Comment: Read them aloud? Have you tried anything?

Comment: i'm edit by adding ready  project if you not try or write any code yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Like `Massimo Cafaro` say :

If you want to extract some content from a pdf file, then you may want to read the following:

[Parsing PDF Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html)

from the Quartz 2D programming guide.

Basically, you will use a `CGPDFScanner` object to parse the contents, which works as follows. You register a few callbacks that will be automatically invoked by Quartz 2D upon encountering some pdf operators in the pdf stream. After this initial step, you then actually start parsing the pdf stream.

Taking a brief look at your code, it appears that you are not following the steps required to parse the pdf content of the page you get through `CGPDFDocumentGetPage()`. You need first to setup the callbacks using `CGPDFOperatorTableCreate()` and `CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback()`, then you get the page, you need to create a content stream using that page (using `CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage()`) and then instantiate a `CGPDFScanner` through `CGPDFScannerCreate()` and actually start scanning through `CGPDFScannerScan()`.

The "Parsing PDF Content" section of the document pointed out by the above URL gives you all of the information required to implement pdf parsing.

if you don't try anything you can start with this project [link](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit)